# Automator and Launchd: OSStatus error -10810

Tags: macos, automator, launchd

I have a number of automator script scheduled in launchd.  All the scripts work fine and execute the workflow as expected.  These are simple workflows that execute some finder actions and shell scripts.  However, I always get an OSStatus 10810 error code on calling them with launchd.  If I create the automator workflow as an application bundle and use "open script.app" I will get the error in job error output.  If I use "automator script.workflow" I don't see anything in the error output of the job, but I do see a similar error code in my server logs.

What is this error in relation to a workflow?

```
Jun 11 15:54:33 MiniServer.local Automator Runner[17094]: Script Monitor is missing or damaged: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The application \u201cScriptMonitor\u201d could not be launched because a miscellaneous error occurred (OSStatus -10810)." 
UserInfo=0x7fb5887c1f50 {NSURL=file:///System/Library/CoreServices/ScriptMonitor.app/, NSLocalizedDescription=The application \u201cScriptMonitor\u201d could not be launched because a miscellaneous error occurred (OSStatus -10810)., 
NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb5887a5250 "The operation couldn\u2019t be completed. (OSStatus error -10810.)"
```